# Why doesn't screen see my alias?

Tags: server, bash, screen

I have this alias in my `.bashrc`

```
...
...
alias server1='for line in `seq 1 10`; do echo "Running server 1: "$line; sleep 1; done'
```

`server1` command works as it should in terminal. But I'm wondering why I cannot start it by running this:

```
screen -S S1_Screen -m server1
```

When I try, I get `Cannot exec 'server1': No such file or directory`

Yet when I fire up a screen like so `screen -S S1_Screen` and then run `server1` manually inside it, it works fine. Why doesn't screen see my alias when I run `screen -S S1_Screen -m server1`?

Comment: you can use a function instead of an alias, then `screen -S A -m bash -c 'server1; exec bash'`

Comment: @bac0n Does not work. I get `bash: server1: command not found`

Comment: where did you put the function (don't forget to source your .bashrc)

Comment: Oh you're saying create a function `server1` and have it run that `for...` command. Got it.

Comment: another example `screen -S A -m bash -c 'bash --rcfile <(cat ~/.profile; echo "echo test")'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man bash`:

```
Aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the first
word of a simple  command.The shell maintains a list of aliases that may be
set and unset with the alias and unalias builtin commands (see SHELL BUILTIN
COMMANDS below). The first word of each simple command, if unquoted, is checked
to see if it has an alias. If so, that word is replaced by the text of the alias.
```

The first word in your command `screen -S S1_Screen -m server1` is `screen`, not `server1`!

Comment: This is certainly true, but the first word of the command inside the spawned screen IS going to be `server1`. Try running `screen -S S1_Screen -m sleep 5`. It will spawn and screen, attach it and run `sleep 5` inside it. Why doesn't it do the same with my alias command? Does it not start bash inside the screen first?

Comment: @codemonkey that's because when you execute `screen -m somecommand`, `screen` executes `somecommand` directly, rather than starting an interactive bash shell in which to execute it

Comment: @steeldriver makes perfect sense now.